# Container for RStudio (not server)

Tags: ubuntu, containers, rstudio, singularity-container, debian-based

I am trying to setup a container for RStudio (not the server!). On our university system (a modified Debian 11), I could not install Rstudio. Therefore, I tried putting together a Singularity recipe. I should have been able to install a .deb file with apt (on an ubuntu image it worked), but for some reason, I needed this ugly way to get it to work.

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: **r-base**

# This is a container to run RStudio

%setup

%files
    rstudio-2023.03.0-386-amd64.deb /rstudio-2023.03.0-386-amd64.deb

%post
    echo "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian bullseye main " > /etc/apt/sources.list # this was needed for libssl1.1
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y systemd libssl1.1 libclang-dev libxkbcommon-x11-0 libsqlite3-0 libpq5 \
    libnss3-dev libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libcups2 libdrm2 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libasound2
    cat /etc/os-release # I needed to know which version of RStudio to install
    dpkg -i /rstudio-2023.03.0-386-amd64.deb
    apt install -y
```

This compiles, but when I try to run, I got the following error:

```
[3433037:0421/161335.902512:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /usr/lib/rstudio/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
Trace/BPT trap
```

If I give it the `--no-sandbox` argument, I get only: `Trace/BPT trap`

This is the exact same error that I get if I try to install it on our system without a container.

Any thoughts or ideas on how to solve this error (**I do not have root to solve it!**)? I also changed `r-base`, which is a Debian based system to `r-ubuntu`, but getting the same error.